# How to pass complex objects within router.navigate() as a query parameter in Angular2

Tags: angular2-routing, query-string

I have configured router configuration with the help of Auxiliary routing in Angular2. So I need to pass a complex object as a query parameter. 
Code example as follows :

```
let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
  queryParams: {
    "person": JSON.stringify({
       "firstname": "Mark",
       "lastname": "Antony",
       "address": {
          "city": "San Francisco",
          "state": "California"
        }
     })
  }
}

this.router.navigate([{outlets: {aux: 'user'}}], navigationExtras)
```

... At the receiving end :

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  this.firsname = params["firstname"];
  this.lastname = params["lastname"];
});
```

When navigating, URL has serailized as a string(encoded). So there were so many wild cards appear in the url. I want to format URL as follows:

```
localhost:4200/main/(aux:user)?firstname=Mark&lastname=Antony&city=San Francisco&state=California
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that it is a good idea to pass the whole object as QueryString.
For security reason and because making URL less useful.
my recommendation is using id and service to get data in other components to retrieve data or use form-data instead of query-string.
But if you want to use QueryString you can use:

[JSON.parse(text[, reviver])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

[JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Your request is custom and tailored to your project...
you can override parse and stringify methods to build string the way you like as long as you following URL rules you will not have any problem like=> (aux:user)
Parentheses is not supporting by url format.

```
JSON.stringfy=(data){
  //foreach property
  //add format and for each nested property look for it's nested properties
  //if your object has more nested property you can use recursive functions.
  //you can use variable to detecting level or making object flat.
}

JSON.parse=()=>{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have reduced the complexity of the object which was ready to pass through the url. Now it is stringify at the sending end and it is passed to a relevant object at the receiving end.